# Pixels are not rendered properly when rendering gif on canvas using konvajs

Tags: javascript, canvas, animated-gif, konvajs

When I add GIF to HTML canvas using konvajs, many pixels of the GIF is not rendered properly.

https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/GIF_On_Canvas.html#page-title
This is the documentation from which I implemented to render GIF on HTML canvas using konvajs
here I used GIF link from Wikipedia GIF instead of "/assets/yoda.gif" in line 49 in the code from the documentation

GIF link from Wikipedia : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif/200px-Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif"

Replace the above URL instead of "/assets/yoda.gif"

I expected to add gif to canvas. It is added but it's glitchy

[image: This is the screenshot of the original gif from the link]

[image: This is the screenshot of the output after I tried the code from the documentation]

Answer (score 1):

The gif file that you are using is an animated gif. This can be seen when the link is opened. To use animated gifs on HTML5 canvas you can use the giffer.js library. See this page from the official Konva docs for an example: https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/GIF_On_Canvas.html

Here is the code in case that doc page is removed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8.4.3/konva.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gifler@0.1.0/gifler.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Konva GIF Demo</title>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight;

  var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: width,
    height: height,
  });

  var layer = new Konva.Layer();
  stage.add(layer);

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  // use external library to parse and draw gif animation
  function onDrawFrame(ctx, frame) {
    // update canvas size
    canvas.width = frame.width;
    canvas.height = frame.height;
    // update canvas that we are using for Konva.Image
    ctx.drawImage(frame.buffer, 0, 0);
    // redraw the layer
    layer.draw();
  }

  gifler('/assets/yoda.gif').frames(canvas, onDrawFrame);

  // draw resulted canvas into the stage as Konva.Image
  var image = new Konva.Image({
    image: canvas,
  });
  layer.add(image);
</script>
```